# How to find the position vector at time t, when given plane curve equation?

Tags: derivatives, vectors

I have a question about the following:
An object moves to the right along the plane curve $y=x^2$ with constant speed $v=5$. find the velocity and acceleration of the object when it is at the point (1,1).

It is concluded from this that the position of the object at time t is: $$\textbf{r}=x\textbf{i}+x^2\textbf{j}$$
But why is this exactly, how can we conclude this from the given info of this question?

If you know the answer and would like to share it with me, it would be very much appreciated :)

thanks in advance

Comment: r is a position vector - it takes an $(x,y)$ coordinate pair and states that it is a vector now. So what is $y$ on the parabola?

Comment: oh I see so you mean that every point needs to be of the form (x,y) that satisfies the equation y = x², so every point is of the form (x,x²), which is in terms of vectornotation => r=xi + x²j @NinadMunshi

Comment: Is this correct @NinadMunshi?

Comment: Yes it is correct

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let's say we denote the time as $t$ and the position of the object is
$$
r(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x(t) \\ y(t) \end{pmatrix}
$$
or in your notation
$$
r(t) = x(t) \mathbf{i} + y(t) \mathbf{j} = x(t) \begin{pmatrix}1 \\ 0 \end{pmatrix} + y(t) \begin{pmatrix}0 \\ 1 \end{pmatrix}.
$$

- Since it has to be on the curve $y = x^2$, we know that $y(t) = x(t)^2$, hence
  $$
  r(t) = \begin{pmatrix} x(t) \\ x(t)^2 \end{pmatrix}
  $$

It is important to notice that $r(t) \neq \begin{pmatrix}t \\ t^2 \end{pmatrix}$! Since then it would not have the correct speed! So, in your question, the variable $x$ depends on time!

- It's velocity should be $v = 5$, so let's compute the velocity:
  $$
  v = \Vert \dot r(t) \Vert = \left\Vert \begin{pmatrix} \dot x(t) \\ 2 x(t) \dot x(t) \end{pmatrix} \right\Vert = \sqrt{ (1+4 x(t)^2) } \Vert \dot x(t) \Vert.
  $$

From this equation, you can see that
$$
\dot x(t) = \pm \frac{5}{\sqrt{1+4x(t)^2}}.
$$

I leave the rest to you. You can use the above equation to determine $\dot x(t)$ and with that, you can find $\dot y(t)$ as well.

Comment: Thank you so much!